# Reading a text line using a given pattern

Tags: c

The question is quite simple, and I hope the answer it's simple too :)

Let's say you are given a pattern, and you have to read a text file, and every line is composed by a first digit, that indicates the number of "patterns" in the string, and the the patterns element separed by one space.

For example, given the pattern

```
key value
```

a valid line of the text file could be

```
3 10 "apple" 15 "orange" 17 "melon"
```

If the number N of repetitions is fixed, I'd use something like

```
fscanf(inFile,"%d %s",&n,str);
```

but is there a function that allows me to give the number of repetitions as a parameter, or I should scan each line and extract values I'm interested in, using substr and atoi?

The "trivial" way is obvious, I'm looking for something more "professional" and effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fscanf() in a loop: first extract the number of repetitions N, then loop N times extracting your pattern.

If you're looking for something more professional or sophisticated, you might want to move away from the standard C library and towards a regex or parsing library, or something mentioned heere: http://www.and.org/vstr/comparison.  While I won't go so far as to say you can't do string processing easily or well in C, it's not a strong point of the core language.

Comment: Looping fscanf seems a fair solution, thanks for your answer :)